# priority-web-sdk: Implementing search fields

Tags: javascript, erp

I'm extending the `fill` function used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734620/priority-web-sdk-implimenting-a-choose-field/44734797#44734797) to populate a `<select>` element with choose-field options so a to handle a search-field.

I have two `<select>` elements in my form, `STATDES` (a choose) and `OWNERLOGIN` (a search).

```
<div id="container" onchange="fieldChangeHandler(event)">
    ...
    <div class="item" >
        <label>Status</label>
        <select id="STATDES" onfocus="focusdiv(event)" onblur="defocusdiv(event)"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="item" >
        <label>Assigned to</label>
        <select id="OWNERLOGIN" onfocus="focusdiv(event)" onblur="defocusdiv(event)"></select>
    </div>
```

I'm checking the `zoom` property of the `column` to determine if I should be reading from `searchObj.ChooseLine` or `searchObj.SearchLine` object.

```
    function fill(el, sel){
        switch (myForm.columns[el.id].zoom){
            case "Choose":
                myForm.choose(el.id, sel).then(
                    function (searchObj) {
                        var i, ch;
                        $('#'+el.id).empty();
                        for (i in searchObj.ChooseLine) {
                            ch = searchObj.ChooseLine[i];
                            if (ch.string1 == sel){
                                $("#"+el.id).append('<option selected value="'+ ch.string1 +'">'+ ch.string1 +'</option>');
                            } else {
                                $('#'+el.id).append('<option value="'+ ch.string1 +'">'+ ch.string1 +'</option>');                  
                            };
                        };
                    },
                    showMessage
                );      
                break;

            case "Search":
                myForm.choose(el.id, sel).then(
                    function (searchObj) {
                        var i, ch;
                        $('#'+el.id).empty();
                        for (i in searchObj.SearchLine) {
                            ch = searchObj.SearchLine[i];
                            if (ch.string2 == sel){
                                $("#"+el.id).append('<option selected value="'+ ch.string2 +'">'+ ch.string2 +'</option>');
                            } else {
                                $('#'+el.id).append('<option value="'+ ch.string2 +'">'+ ch.string2 +'</option>');                  
                            };
                        };
                    },              
                    showMessage
                );  
                break;

        };
    };
```

The `choose` function on `STATDES` returns a `searchObj.ChooseLine` object.

The `choose` function on `OWNERLOGIN` returns a `searchObj.SearchLine` object.

**BUT** both have a zoom type of `Choose`.

```
myForm.columns['STATDES']{
  attachment: 0
  decimal: 0
  field: 5
  format: ""
  mandatory: 1
  maxLength: 12
  readonly: 0
  title: "Status"
  type: "text"
  zoom: "Choose"
}

myForm.columns['OWNERLOGIN']{
  "attachment": 0,
  "decimal": 0,
  "field": 6,
  "format": "",
  "mandatory": 1,
  "maxLength": 20,
  "readonly": 0,
  "title": "Assigned to",
  "type": "text",
  "zoom": "Choose"
}
```

How do I differentiate please?

Comment: Can you differentiate using the `title` property ?

Comment: Thanks, but no, because the `title` could be anything, depending on which columns are dynamically included in the form. I need to be able to work out how to handle the column based on the `zoom` property.

Comment: Can you add a custom key to it ? Which you can check later to classify which type.

Comment: Same problem I'm afraid. If I were adding a custom type I'd need to know what `zoom` type to set it. `myForm.columns['OWNERLOGIN'].customkey=?`

Comment: The thing is you are checking `myForm.columns[el.id].zoom` in your switch case, which you are saying has `Choose` as value for both the two types. There has to be some unique identifier, else your switch case is of no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are a lot of choose results, the Web-SDK will return a Search object in order to allow dealing with a search even though `zoom=Choose`. So as @naomi suggested the right way of deciding whether the results are of a Choose or a Search would be checking if the resulting object contains `Searchline` or `Chooseline`.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a variable to contain the search results and assign one of the `SearchLine` or `ChooseLine` results, depending on the one that exists. Then simply use that variable.

```
 myForm.choose(el.id, sel).then(
   function (searchObj) {
     const searchResults = searchObj.SearchLine ? searchObj.SearchLine : searchObj.ChooseLine;
     var i, ch;
     $('#'+el.id).empty();
     for (i in searchResults) {
        ch = searchResults[i];
        ...
     }
   },showMessage);
```

If you would like to know whether the field is a search field (and use the [searchAction](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#searchAction) method) you could simply check the existance of the `SearchLine` in the `SearchObj` result.

```
const isSearchField = searchObj.SearchLine !== undefined
```